# Where to put configuration / settings data in PHP MVC application?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, config

I'm building PHP MVC-like application for learning purpose and I'm stuck with where to put configuration/settings files/data in application.

I have some core app configuration like database info, default and allowed languages, some root url to web app, timezone and more. But I also have something like application name, description, url, default email, location, phone number etc.

I placed core app config in Config folder (available only for developers) - **Config/database.php**, **Config/app.php** etc... Where should I place data like app name, description, email etc so that end user can change it if he like - in database, some external language file or ? I need both of those data sets across application in Entities, Controllers for redirection etc...

My config.php file:

```
return array
(
    'app' => array (
        'root' => 'http://www.website.com/',
        'timezone' => 'Europe/London'
    ),

    'language' => array (
        'default' => 'en',
        'allowed' => array('en', 'de', 'it')
    ),

    'database' => array (
        'name' => 'db_name',
        'username' => 'db_user',
        'password' => 'db_pass',
        'type' => 'mysql',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'options' => array (
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true
        )
    ),
);
```

Comment: there are likely to be many many opinions on which way is better. but [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-config/) might give you a good starting point.

Comment: thanks, very good article, i think i will separate my main/core configuration in config file and other app settings in database and/or in language files. Also, I have information about different app url (en - www.website.com, de - www.website.com/de/) and different time/hour format, where to put data like this ?

Comment: I would go with php array config and use serialize on it for cache and performance gain.

Comment: There a couple similar questions with good answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368329/best-way-to-store-a-php-apps-settings) 
and  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809241/php-application-config-file-stored-as-ini-php-sql-cached-php-class-json-php).